# Get One column in join from same table but different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two database.

a. `DB_1`   b. `DB_2`

let say, I am currently using `DB_1` for my below query

```
Select top 1 a.mkey,convert(varchar(255), a.ref_date,103) as REF_DATE,  cd.type_desc as DOC_TYPE,  a.doc_no as INWARD_NO, 
                       cr.type_desc as dept_received, e.emp_name as EMP_RECEIVED,    
                       convert(varchar(255), a.doc_date,103) as date,   
                       a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No,    
                       e.emp_name as NAME,    
                       coalesce(e.Email_Id_Official, 'test@test.com') EMAILID, a.Party_Name                           
                from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a left join   
                     type_mst_a cd   
                     on a.doc_type = cd.master_mkey left join  
                   type_mst_a cr   
                     on a.dept_received = cr.master_mkey 
                     and cr.type_code='D1'  
                     left join  emp_mst e  
                     on a.emp_received = e.mkey   
                     where a.emp_received is not null and
                        a.mkey = 146
```

Now what I want is. I want to join the same table from another database(`DB_2`) how to do that ??

**UPDATE**

My another db column name is `Inward_ref_key` and its table name is `inward_doc_tracking_hdr`

Comment: you need to make sure you can link to DB2 from DB1 and then use the DB_2.<schema>.<tablename> to get what you want.

Comment: @Raffaello.D.HukeL Yes, they are on same server. I am able to link them too. but i m stuck with joi issue

Comment: Let's say you have schema.table1 in DB2 could you do this on DB1? "select * from [DB2].schema.table1" please remember ,DB2 is the name of DB2 , if you can do this select part, then the join is just like that. i ll give you an example by post an answer XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed. Please see answer below.

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.mkey,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), a.ref_date,103) AS REF_DATE, 
    cd.type_desc AS DOC_TYPE, 
    a.doc_no AS INWARD_NO, 
    cr.type_desc AS dept_received, 
    e.emp_name AS EMP_RECEIVED, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), a.doc_date,103) AS DATE, 
    a.to_user,
    a.No_of_pages,
    Ref_No, 
    e.emp_name AS NAME, 
    COALESCE(e.Email_Id_Official, 'test@test.com') EMAILID, 
    a.Party_Name, 
    doc_no = (SELECT TOP 1 doc_no FROM erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr WHERE mkey = a.inward_ref_key)
    OLD_DOC_NO 
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a 
LEFT JOIN type_mst_a cd 
    ON cd.master_mkey  = a.doc_type  
LEFT JOIN type_mst_a cr 
    ON cr.master_mkey = a.dept_received 
    AND cr.type_code='D1' 
LEFT JOIN emp_mst e 
    ON  e.mkey = a.emp_received
WHERE a.emp_received IS NOT NULL 
AND a.mkey = 146
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thanks @mvisser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both databases are on the same server, all you have to do is specify the other database as a part of the table identifier:

```
DB_2.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr
```

If your table belongs to a different schema (not `dbo`), specify that schema name.

Comment: but how to join the column via using alias ??

Comment: See, I have `Inward_ref_key` column of `inward_doc_tracking_hdr` which should come from `db_2`. I want to join that. how will I do

Comment: Same as always. the fact that one comes from `DB_1` and the other from `DB_2` is irrelevant - you can give each one any alias you want...

Comment: can u tell me one thing, I need to add one sub query after `a.party_name`. like this `a.Inward_ref_key (Select doc_no from erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr) Ref` is it right ? I tried this but it was not working

Comment: the sub query which I tried to get `Inward_ref_key` that is giving error.

Comment: I'm guessing `subquery returned more then one value...` Please edit your question and add the relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML and desired results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116345/discussion-between-n-k-and-zohar-peled).

Comment: if possbile come on chat, I will explain you in details

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference a table from another database you go this way:

```
DB_2.<schema>.<table_name>
```

Be careful if they have different collations

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT local.name AS LocalLogins, linked.name AS LinkedLogins  
FROM master.sys.server_principals AS local  
LEFT JOIN [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.server_principals AS linked  
ON local.name = linked.name ;  
GO
```

here the [SRVR002\ACCTG] is the DB's name, if you already created the DBlink, this should works